# how to set values for xlabels and ylabels in mpandroidchart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using mpandroidchart android library. I am implementing line charts. Here can i set the x and y labels on my own? currently it is adding the values based on the dataset provided to the chart. Can you please give some idea on this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a formatter on your axis object.

There is two kind of formatter XAxisValueFormatter and YAxisValueFormatter.

This the code i used to change the X label number with suffix "h" for hours :

```
//get reference on chart line view
LineChart chart = (LineChart) pActivity.findViewById(R.id.chart);
//set formater for x Label
chart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new XAxisValueFormatter() {

        @Override
        public String getXValue(String original, int index, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
            //return number + "h" here
            // but you can do everything you want here. The string returned will be displayed on chart x label
            return original + "h";
        }
    });
//axis to the bottom
chart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
//populate with data
chart.setData(data);
// refresh
chart.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific? For the x-labels you can set whatever you want in the data object you provide. For the y-labels, call `setYRange(...)` to set a fixed range of values to show.

Comment: Hi, actually i was looking for setting the range and formatting. I used value formatter for that which worked for me.

Comment: But now I wanted to know whether can i have null values in the middle of line chart? Say for instance i have a data set of 10 x vals and 10 yvals. Now in a yval i want to make it as null which means the xval for the same will exists but no yval. There would be no dot in the line chart. Is this possible?

Comment: I think this is a follow up question to this: Phil, how can I show more XLabels, e.g. make them denser? I have tried setting getXLabels().setSpaceBetweenLabels(1); but it does not seem to change the spacing. Best regards