# How to set the x-axis label with MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I use MPAndroidChart for my app like this:

[image]

but I can not add tag like that

Comment: What about showing what you have _tried_ so far?

Comment: I don't think you can "group" the existing axis labels. I do think that the API has a method to change the labels, though. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061803/how-to-set-values-for-xlabels-and-ylabels-in-mpandroidchart

Comment: I had showed the label, but the position of label is wrong,because the getFormattedValue always return 0,4,8,12,16,20;

Answer (score 30):

Do you need your **tag** instead of those **values**?

If so, then here it goes the method to do so.

Add your `XAxis` labels to an `ArrayList`

```
    final ArrayList<String> xLabel = new ArrayList<>();
    xLabel.add("9");
    xLabel.add("15");
    xLabel.add("21");
    xLabel.add("27");
    xLabel.add("33");  

    // or use some other logic to save your data in list. For ex. 
    for(i=1; i<50; i+=2)
    { 
       xLabel.add(""+3*i);
    }
```

then use this label in the `setValueFormatter`.
**Ex**:

```
    XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            return xLabel.get((int)value);
        }
    });
```

**Result**:

[image]

Comment: But, sometimes tag is repeated.. :( Any edits will be helpful.

Comment: Having the same issue with this

Comment: there's an option to set Granularity.Set it to 1.then it will not repeat when zooming

Comment: `value` is not the position of the entry, aren't you treating it like a position?

Comment: I am getting this error `error: incompatible types: <anonymous IAxisValueFormatter> cannot be converted to ValueFormatter
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {`

Comment: I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67379636/6854117) related to it can you please see it?

Answer (score 5):

You can override AxisValueFormatter

i.e.:

```
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new AxisValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
                return "YOUR_TEXT"; // here you can map your values or pass it as empty string
            }

            @Override
            public int getDecimalDigits() {
                return 0; //show only integer
            }
        });
```

You can pick center value of the group to map the group name, others are empty. that would be the easiest way.

Comment: thank you for your answer .but the return value always is 0,4,8,12,16,20 when i used getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) and my center value is 3,9,15,21。and i will make my label position is wrong

Comment: I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67379636/6854117) related to it can you please see it?

Answer (score 4):

I tried this version: `implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'`:

```
public class BarChartActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bar_chart2);

        BarChart chart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.barchart);

        int[] numArr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        List<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
        for (int num : numArr) {
            entries.add(new BarEntry(num, num));
        }
        BarDataSet dataSet = new BarDataSet(entries, "Numbers");
        BarData data = new BarData(dataSet);

        ValueFormatter xAxisFormatter = new DayAxisValueFormatter(chart);
        XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        xAxis.setGranularity(1f); // only intervals of 1 day
        xAxis.setLabelCount(7);
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(xAxisFormatter);

        chart.setData(data);
        chart.invalidate();
    }

    public class DayAxisValueFormatter extends ValueFormatter {
        private final BarLineChartBase<?> chart;
        public DayAxisValueFormatter(BarLineChartBase<?> chart) {
            this.chart = chart;
        }
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
            return "your text " + value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: In your above code if we use month arrays to DayAxisValueFormatter  it is not showing all the labels.

Comment: I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67379636/6854117) related to it can you please see it?

Comment: how to remove description label at the end of the xaxis

Comment: @AbhilashReddy description.isEnabled = false if using Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

I find another solution to this problem. try to add these params

```
float groupSpace = 0.06f;
float barSpace = 0.02f;
mChart.setData(data);
mChart.groupBars(0f, groupSpace, barSpace);
```

Comment: I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67379636/6854117) related to it can you please see it?