# X Axis Labels not showing up, using MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I want to have x axis labels on my linechart (using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)) but no matter what I do, I can't get them to display. I have a method called setupChart which handles everything for that chart and this is what it looks like:

```
private void setupChart(LineChart chart, LineData data, int color) {

    ((LineDataSet) data.getDataSetByIndex(0)).setCircleColorHole(Color.WHITE);
    ((LineDataSet) data.getDataSetByIndex(0)).setCircleColor(color);
    ((LineDataSet) data.getDataSetByIndex(0)).setColors(dataColors);
    data.getDataSetByIndex(0).setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    ((LineDataSet) data.getDataSetByIndex(0)).setDrawCircles(false);

    // no description text
    chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);

    // mChart.setDrawHorizontalGrid(false);
    //
    // enable / disable grid background
    chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

    // enable touch gestures
    chart.setTouchEnabled(true);

    // disable scaling and dragging
    chart.setDragEnabled(false);
    chart.setScaleEnabled(false);
    chart.setAutoScaleMinMaxEnabled(false);
    // if disabled, scaling can be done on x- and y-axis separately
    chart.setPinchZoom(false);
    chart.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#dddddd"));

    // set custom chart offsets (automatic offset calculation is hereby disabled)
    chart.setViewPortOffsets(10, 0, 10, 0);
    // add data
    chart.setData(data);

    // get the legend (only possible after setting data)
    Legend l = chart.getLegend();
    l.setEnabled(false);

    chart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);

    chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    chart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    chart.getXAxis().setEnabled(false);
    chart.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(true);
    chart.getXAxis().setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    chart.getXAxis().setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
    YAxis yAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
    yAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
    yAxis.setAxisMaximum(100f);

    final String[] weeks = new String[52];

    for(int i = 0; i < weeks.length; i++) weeks[i] = "Week " + (i+1);

    IAxisValueFormatter formatter = new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            return weeks[(int) value];
        }
    };

    XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(formatter);
    // animate calls invalidate()...
    chart.animateXY(2000,2500);
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: which version of library are you using?

Comment: @santalu version 3.0.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41499401/7461132 might solve the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved this by increasing my offsets:

```
chart.setViewPortOffsets(60, 0, 50, 60);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
linechart.setExtraBottomOffset(ff)
```

Modifying the offsets will help you to solve this problem as well.

Adjust the (ff) float values to get desired space.

Answer (score 2):

My chart was not showing x-axis and y-axis. I remove this line the x-axis and y-axis appeared.

when this line exist `lineChart.setViewPortOffsets(0,0,0,0)` the chart look like this

[image]

when I remove this line `lineChart.setViewPortOffsets(0,0,0,0)` the chart look like this

[image]